# Advantages and use of cman cluster

Tags: linux, cman

Can anyone tell me what are the advantages of cman cluster and what is a node meant while configuring a server.

Does a node identify a server? or how is it?

I want to configure a cman cluster with two nodes. can anyone tell me how can i configure it and what all hardware,software should be used and cman cluster configuration steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Step 1 2 Blade server 
Step 2 each server minimum 4 NIC card
Step 3 Vanilla Cent OS 6.4
Step 4 Create a local repo
Step 5 Using yum install cman rgmanager luci ricci (1st server )
Step 6 Using yum install cman rgmanager ricci (2nd server)
Step 7 passwd ricci (both server)
Step 8 Selinux disable & chkconfig iptables off chkconfig ip6tables
Step 9 Add hostname to /etc/hosts both server name (node1.cluster.com & node2.cluster.com and ipaddress) 
Step 10 Create eth0 & eth1 = bond0 (should be back to back connected)
Step 11 Create eth2 & eth3 = bond1 (production IP)
Step 12 reboot once both the server
Step 13 chkconfig cman on && chkconfig rgmanger on && chkconfig ricci on && chkconfig luci on
Step 14 luci_admin init create luci passwd
Step 15 service luci restart && service ricci restart (on 1st server Point your web browser to https://localhost:8084 to access luci)
Step 16 service ricci restart (on 2nd server)
Step 17 service cman restart && service rgmanager restart (on both server )
Step 18 now you need config you cluster
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 1.can i use two virtual machines as two nodes and how these two will be clusterd.2.can i use two seperate hp servers as two nodes and how will be the connectivity of clustering between these two servers

Comment: Thanks for the reply 1.can i use two virtual machines as two nodes and how these two will be clusterd.2.can i use two seperate hp servers as two nodes and how will be the connectivity of clustering between these two servers

Comment: Visit following video link
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cegjvhr7m2s